# Magento - Need to bypass built-in custom options system and populate custom options from an external PHTML file

Tags: magento

The company I work for is currently in the process of moving over our site from a full HTML site with no CMS to Magento. Our products are very customizable and a lot of the options that are available are dependent on each other. I also have our menu system (and how it appears) dependent on the currently-selected product options. This being said, Magento's custom options system does not (out of the box) allow for the customization I need to make the product's options menu work the way I need. Instead of trying to re-invent the Magento wheel, I figured the easiest way to do this would be to have the item pull the custom options from a PHTML file. This way I can specify which options to pull based on the product type (an attribute). I was able to get that part working fine. The issues I am having are as follows:

1. price will not update when options are selected
2. options are not sent to cart when i add to cart

How can I bypass Magento's built-in custom options system and still have my custom options (from the phtml file) send to the cart when you add along with changing the price? Hope I was clear. Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the data from the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml` file so that Magento dynamically pulls the pricing and custom option data that will be present on the product page.

You will include all scripting (between the `script` tags), and be sure the custom options are between the `dl` tags unless you're using completely custom CSS work.

Exclude all PHP language from the options.phtml file if you're going to dump the options directly into a phtml file.

This allows the pricing to dynamically update with the selections made and allows the custom options to be added to the cart.